# Block ICMP echo responses using the Windows Firewall

Tags: windows, firewall, ping, icmp

I'd like to block ICMP Echo **Reply** messages from leaving a Windows 10 computer, but still have Echo Requests come in.

I created an Outbound rule, but couldn't see which option to choose for replies.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: This might be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Consider the points addressed here: http://shouldiblockicmp.com/

Comment: Thanks Doug. I've written a program which logs ICMP Echo Requests (think honeypot) and I would like to prevent the ICMP Echo Responses.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking there's really not a lot to gain from a security perspective by blocking ICMP replies, so if that's your main motivation it's probably more worthwhile to focus on other areas.

To answer your question, ICMPv4 Echo Reply has a `Type` of `0` ([RFC 792](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc792)), and the corresponding ICMPv6 `Type` is `129` ([RFC 4443](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4443#section-4.2)). In theory you should be able to allow inbound ICMP Echo requests and block these specific types of outbound traffic, but doing so has no discernible effect when I try it on a Windows Server 2012 R2 VM.

Comment: Windows Firewall is stateful, which in rough terms means that if a packet is allowed, then the response to that packet is also allowed even if it otherwise wouldn't be.  Usually that means allowing an incoming packet because it is in response to a previous outgoing packet, but perhaps it works the other way around as well?

Answer (score 0):

As Mikael suggested, it is possible to create a rule which blocks outbound ICMP Echo Replies. Steps below.

However the rule has no discernible effect on the Echo Replies sent by Windows. It appears to only block Echo Replies originating from programs running in User Space.

[image]
[image]